# Confusion on React Callback's on Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am attempting to learn react along with rails (Using rails purely as an API). Im making a simple to-do app and getting stuck when attempting to "Create" a list.

I have a "New List" component shown here, mostly taken from the react forms tutorial:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ListForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        title: '',
        description: ''
      };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
      console.log("Form submitted with: " + this.state.value)
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Title:
            <input name="title" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Description:
            <textarea name="description" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  export default ListForm;
```

I have my ListContainer shown here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import List from './List';
import ListForm from './ListForm'

class ListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lists: []
        }

        this.addNewList = this.addNewList.bind(this)
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/v1/lists.json')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.setState({
                lists: response.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    addNewList(title, description) {
        axios.post('/api/v1/lists.json', {
            title: title,
            description: description
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            const lists = [ ...this.state.lists, response.data ]
            console.log(...this.state.lists)
            this.setState({lists})
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="lists-container">
                {this.state.lists.map( list => {
                    return (<List list={list} key={list.id} />)
                })}
                <ListForm onSubmit={this.addNewList} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListContainer;
```

My issue comes from a misunderstanding at the callback on submit. I understand that when I do an "onSubmit" on the form it's using addNewList function as a callback....but I really am not understanding how the connection from state in the ListForm is getting into that callback function. I obviously am doing something wrong because it does not work and currently console shows "Form submitted with: undefined" so it's not passing parameters correctly at all.

Im still pretty new to React and very rusty with JS (It's been a bit since i've used it so im sure there are some newbie mistakes here). Also axios is basically a "better" fetch fwiw.

I won't lie either, I don't exactly understand why we do `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);` for example (along with the other similar ones)

Comment: can u create a js fiddle plzz it will be easy to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close! We just need to make a few adjustments.

First let's lose the bind statements, and just use arrow functions. Arrow functions have no `this` object, and so if you call on `this` inside that function, you will actually access the `this` object of your class instance. Neat.

Second, let's fix the typo on your handleChange function, so that your inputs are updating the component state properly.

Now, the real solution to your problem. You need to call the addNewList function in your parent component, ListContainer. How do we do that? Lets pass it down to the child component as a prop! You're almost there, but instead of using the keyword `onSubmit={this.addNewList}`, lets use something like `handleSubmit` instead. This is because onSubmit is actually a special keyword that will attach an event listener to the child component for submit, and we don't want that.

Now that your child component is taking in your function as a prop. We can call it inside the handleSubmit function. We then pass in the arguments, title and description. Now your child component is able to call the addNewList function in the parent component!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import List from './List';
import ListForm from './ListForm'

class ListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lists: []
        }

        this.addNewList = this.addNewList.bind(this)
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/v1/lists.json')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    lists: response.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    addNewList(title, description) {
        axios.post('/api/v1/lists.json', {
            title: title,
            description: description
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                const lists = [...this.state.lists, response.data]
                console.log(...this.state.lists)
                this.setState({ lists })
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="lists-container">
                {this.state.lists.map(list => {
                    return (<List list={list} key={list.id} />)
                })}
                <ListForm handleSubmit={this.addNewList} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListContainer;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ListForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            description: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.handleSubmit(this.state.title, this.state.description);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Title:
            <input name="title" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Description:
            <textarea name="description" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
```

Comment: Ah! that makes so much more sense. I was curious why the tutorials I was using were still using bind with the arrow functions out but I thought it was just a react thing. Glad to know that fixes that. At least I was close! lol.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo as well. For the change event you have

```
<input name="title" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

So the callback for change is `this.handleInputChange`. But in your code its called `handleChange`

But even if you've used the right naming, it will not work, because you need to bind that function as well.

That brings me to your question about `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

The problem here is that when you pass a function as a callback it loses its context. Consider the following

```
const x = { 
  log: function() { console.log(this.val) },
  val: 10
}
```

Now you can do

```
x.log(); // -> print 10
```

But when you do

```
y = x.log;
y(); // -> prints undefined
```

If you pass only the function around it looses its context. To fix this you can `bind`

```
x.log = x.log.bind(x);
y = x.log
y(); // -> prints 10
```

Hope this makes sense :)

Anyway, to come back to you question, you don't have to use bind, there is a better way

```
class ListForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    title: '',
    description: ''
  };
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  console.log("Form submitted with: " + this.state.value)
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Although not tests, it might work right now!

Answer (score 0):

Change value property of the inputs with `this.state.title` & `this.state.description`:

```
<input name="title" type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
<textarea name="description" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

try printing info using

```
console.log("Form submitted with: ", this.state)
```

Regards to the `.bind(this)` :

- When any event fires, an event object is assigned to callback function. So callback function or event handlers loses reference to class and `this` points to whichever event has been called.
- Bind creates a new function that will have this set to the first parameter passed to bind()
- Apart from `.bind(this)` arrow function takes care for `this`. but it's not preferable for long hierarchy.